# Translate non-integer days to an actual date in java?

Tags: java, date

How would I calculate an exact date from a floating point value (example 3.47 days ago) in Java?

Comment: `LocalDateTime.now().minusMinutes((long)(3.47 * 60 * 24));` ?

Comment: If the day is, say, 23 or 25 hours long, which is the case by summer time transitions, would you want the 0.47 days taken as this fraction of the number of hours in the day?

Answer (score 1):

Internally, Java Dates are stored as a long, which represents, as the documentation says, "the number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT".

You can get that long value from a Date by calling it's `getTime()` method.

You can create a Date from a long by using it's constructor that takes a long, e.g. `new Date(myLongValue)`.

So, you can calculate the number of milliseconds in a day, get the current time as a long, subtract (3.47 * millisecondsInADay) from that, and then use the resulting value to construct a new Date.

Note that "number of milliseconds in a day" could be a problem, depending on the accuracy that you need, and the situations to which you want to apply this.

Comment: In 2021 (and actually since 2014) I recommend we don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or another class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: agreed, but was answering the question as asked.

Comment: The question wisely does not mention the `Date` class (or any other outdated class).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is OK to convert provided number of days to seconds (missing some fractional parts for ease) here is the code that converts number of days to seconds and subtracts such number of seconds (as Duration) from current time based on local machine (as per LocalDateTime.now()):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double daysAgo = 3.47;
    LocalDateTime timeAgo = getTimeAgo(daysAgo);
    System.out.println("Time ago: " + timeAgo);
}

public static LocalDateTime getTimeAgo(double daysAgo) {
    long secondsAgo = secondsFromDays(daysAgo);
    Duration duration = Duration.of(secondsAgo, ChronoUnit.SECONDS);

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    System.out.println("Starting time: " + now);
    return now.minus(duration);
}

public static long secondsFromDays(double days) {
    return (long) (days * 24 * 60 * 60);
}
```

Result:

```
Starting time: 2021-06-28T22:31:16.242040100
Time ago: 2021-06-25T11:14:28.242040100
```